# Difference between approach maneuvers to the insertion points of halo and Lissajous orbit?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbital-maneuver, halo-orbit

I have read that spacecraft use two mid-course corrections to approach the Lagrange point, then do a final orbital insertion maneuver to enter into a halo orbit.

Are there any specifics about this maneuver that can be explained to me considering I did not get through Classical Mechanics in my college days, many decades ago, so a highly technical answer will be way over my head.

I understand that halo orbits are constrained to one plane where lissajous orbits are not.

Is there a distinct difference between such a maneuver for a halo orbit compared to a lissajous orbit?

Comment: I wrote a whole answer to the title of your question before realizing that the body of your question asks about mid-course corrections and orbital maneuvers. I've added this back into your title, and added the appropriate tags. For the differences in the orbits themselves, see [What is the difference between halo orbits and Lissajous orbits?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31502/12102) where I've moved my answer.

Comment: Both halos and Lissaojous' are *roughly planar*, though it's the planar Lyapunov orbits and their kin that are really planar. You can see a 3D plot [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OL8gz.gif) of SOHO's approach to it's true halo orbit in the question [Is this what station keeping maneuvers look like, or just glitches in data? (SOHO via Horizons)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/16644/12102) as well as other goodies.

Comment: also see https://space.stackexchange.com/a/24516/12102

Comment: I thought Lissajous orbits are not planar.  The Lyapunov orbit are on the same plane of the orbits of the the two bodies in question, and halo orbits are perpendicular.  I read that Lissajous orbits have components in both the plane and the perpendicular.

Comment: There are *planar Lyapunov orbits* which are planar, and there are vertical Lyapunov orbits which are on curved surfaces, as are Lissajous and halos (which are a kind of Lissajous). In reality, using computers rather than pen and paper, a ton of completely different CR3BP orbits have been classified. It's quite a big list. See https://space.stackexchange.com/a/27603/12102